# SqlDataAdapter does not delete the rows from the table

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

I have set of Ids in a C# DataTable. At the same time, I have a table containing those IDs and some other data too. My requirement is to delete the records which contains the IDs specified in the data table ( if there are tuples with that IDs).

I'm using SqlDataAdapter for that.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(text, con);


command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
PrepareCommand(command, con, null, type, text, commandParas);

SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adpt.DeleteCommand = command;

adpt.UpdateBatchSize = 2;

adpt.Update(dataTable);

connection.Close();
```

Here what I mean by,

```
- "text" is the name of the stored procedure containing the delete command. The argument given to this stored procedure is the ID ( picked from the list of IDs contained in the data table) 

- "commandParas" is the argument passed to the stored procedure.

- "dataTable" contains the Ids used to delete the rows from  SQL table. It contains only one column but several rows.
```

But this does not result in specified rows being removed the table.

***EDIT***

I have given the stored procedure below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someName(@ID INT)
AS
BEGIN
     DELETE FROM SampleTable
     WHERE id=@ID
END
```

What I have given below is the code where I create the data table

```
   DataTable dt=new DataTable("abc");
   dt.clear();
   dt.Columns.Add(empId,typeof(int));

   foreach(SomeClass t SomeList)
         dt.Rows.Add(t.IdNo);
```

Have I made any mistake ?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to use SqlAdapter for deleting records? You can use SqlCommand for this.

Comment: Visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**. You did not provided SQL stored procedure, `PrepareCommand` and how you are passing id to the stored procedure and all that.

Comment: @Selva TS : anything that can help me to delete the rows is fine. But I have to pass the set of Ids, not a single Id. That is a must. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya : sorry...I will provide the stored procedure too. Please let me know if you have a solution to this

Comment: @nidarshanifernando What is your Database? `Sql Server 2008` or later? If it so, we can use `TableValueParameter` for this scenario.

Comment: @Selva TS : Unfortunately, it is 2005. I tried using TableValue Parameters, but it was not possible because of the version

Answer (score 0):

I see you call `PrepareCommand`, and set it into the adapter as the adapter's DeleteCmmand, but where do you run the command?

Comment: Ok, can you also add the code where you set which rows should be deleted.

Comment: I have just added that part too

Comment: Great, but you still need to call delete on the rows in the datatable that you want to delete.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13.aspx for some guidance.  So right now you have rows in the datatable, but until you mark them for deletion, the delete command won't get invoked, because there is nothing to delete.

Answer (score 0):

As [DWright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49251/dwright) pointed out, you have to set the rows to be deleted in the `DataTable` before pushing it into `SqlDataAdapter` Batch Operations. The following code is works when I set rows as deleted.

```
        DataTable dt;

        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Dealer]", c))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }

        dt.Rows[0].Delete();
        dt.Rows[1].Delete();
        dt.Rows[2].Delete();

        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            var command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Dealer WHERE DealerId = @DealerId;", c);

            var parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@DealerId", SqlDbType.Int, 3, "DealerId");
            parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

            adapter.DeleteCommand = command;
            adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

            adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 2;
            adapter.Update(dt);
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. I set rows to be deleted before passing it to the Update() method. It generates the following exception "system.InvalidOperationException: Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows."

Comment: @nidarshanifernando so you have new rows also in the `DataTable`?

Comment: If so, please use `Update` and `Insert` command as given in this example, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

After programatically adding the rows to the table, call AcceptChanges.